# Unity C#: how to convert an Array of a class into JSON

Tags: arrays, json, unity-game-engine

I need to save multiple player's data. I am doing it by making an array of PlayersInfo class and trying to convert the array into JSON. here is my code

```
  PlayerInfo[] allPlayersArray = new PlayerInfo[1];

  allPlayersArray[0] = new PlayerInfo();
  allPlayersArray[0].playerName = "name 0";

  string allPlayersArrayJson = JsonUtility.ToJson(allPlayersArray);
  print(allPlayersArrayJson);
  PlayerPrefs.SetString("allPlayersArrayJson", allPlayersArrayJson);

  string newJson = PlayerPrefs.GetString("allPlayersArrayJson");
  print(newJson);

  PlayerInfo[] newArray = new PlayerInfo[1];

  newArray = JsonUtility.FromJson<PlayerInfo[]>(newJson);

  print(newArray[0].playerName);
```

First two print statements returns "{}" and 3rd one gives null reference error. TIA

Comment: Unity Json Serializer does not support this directly. You need a helper class for it to work. I think that this is a duplicate question. Here is your answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/36244111/3785314 Start reading from where it says **2.MULTIPLE DATA(ARRAY JSON)**

Comment: Thanks @Programmer, Can you please help me how I actually use it? I just copied the helper class now I wonder how I use it to convert my arrays? Please note I need to modify that array further.

Comment: The link to the answer I posted shows you steps to do that. Scroll down and try to follow them. If there is a problem then let me know. I will then post a solution. You must tell me what you tried before I post an answer.

Comment: Here is what I tried.    'PlayerInfo[] firstArray = new PlayerInfo[1];
firstArray[0].playerName = "Name1";
string firstJSON = JsonHelper.ToJson(firstArray);
PlayerPrefs.SetString("playerInfo", firstJSON);
string firstString = PlayerPrefs.GetString("playerInfo");
PlayerInfo[] secondArray = new PlayerInfo[1];
secondArray = JsonHelper.FromJson<PlayerInfo>(firstString);
secondArray[0].playerName = "Name2";
string secondString = JsonHelper.ToJson(secondArray);
PlayerPrefs.SetString("playerInfo", secondString);
string thirdString = PlayerPrefs.GetString("playerInfo");

Comment: But it gives null reference error on 2nd statement.

Comment: Ok Making an answer for this specific post.

Comment: Thank you very much, waiting for it

Comment: Your problem is a little-bit different and does not require some steps on that I posted.I tested the solution I posted and It works for me. Try it. If that's not working for you, please update to Unity 5.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like I said in my comment, there is no direct support. [Helper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36244111/3785314) class is needed. This is only reason I am making this answer is because you are still having problems even after reading the link I provided.

Create a new script called `JsonHelper`. Copy and paste the code below inside it.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;

public class JsonHelper
{

    public static T[] FromJson<T>(string json)
    {
        Wrapper<T> wrapper = UnityEngine.JsonUtility.FromJson<Wrapper<T>>(json);
        return wrapper.Items;
    }

    public static string ToJson<T>(T[] array)
    {
        Wrapper<T> wrapper = new Wrapper<T>();
        wrapper.Items = array;
        return UnityEngine.JsonUtility.ToJson(wrapper);
    }

    [Serializable]
    private class Wrapper<T>
    {
        public T[] Items;
    }
}
```

The code in your question should now work. All you have to do is to replace  all `JsonUtility` words with `JsonHelper`. I did that for you below:

```
void Start()
{
    PlayerInfo[] allPlayersArray = new PlayerInfo[1];

    allPlayersArray[0] = new PlayerInfo();
    allPlayersArray[0].playerName = "name 0";

    string allPlayersArrayJson = JsonHelper.ToJson(allPlayersArray);
    print(allPlayersArrayJson);
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("allPlayersArrayJson", allPlayersArrayJson);

    string newJson = PlayerPrefs.GetString("allPlayersArrayJson");
    print(newJson);

    PlayerInfo[] newArray = new PlayerInfo[1];

    newArray = JsonHelper.FromJson<PlayerInfo>(newJson);

    print(newArray[0].playerName);
}
```

Comment: It worked as sample. Thank you. Let me try it later on my real project and I'll tick it as an answer.

Comment: Take your time. Let me know if there is any problem. Although, there shouldn't any.

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the JsonUtility [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.ToJson.html), naked arrays are not supported. Put the array inside a class.

> Internally, this method uses the Unity serializer; therefore the
>   object you pass in must be supported by the serializer: it must be a
>   MonoBehaviour, ScriptableObject, or plain class/struct with the
>   Serializable attribute applied.

In general, you'll use this to serialize `MonoBehaviour` objects, or a custom class/struct with the `Serializable` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

YES! It is not supported currently but there is always a work around. Use this class :

```
public static class JsonHelper
{
    public static T[] getJsonArray<T>(string json)
    {
        try
        {
            string newJson = "{ \"array\": " + json + "}";
            Wrapper<T> wrapper = JsonUtility.FromJson<Wrapper<T>> (newJson);
            return wrapper.array;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    private class Wrapper<T>
    {
        public T[] array = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

```
PlayerInfo[] allPlayersArray = new PlayerInfo[] { p1, p2, p3 };

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(allPlayersArray);
```

[More On SerializeObject](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm)

*(Code example not yet tested)*