# I'm trying to parse json via www (Unity)

Tags: c#, json, parsing, unity-game-engine

I have a Config.json file, when i try to parse it when it is in my local drive it works, but when i'm trying to parse it via www i get this error: "ArgumentException: JSON parse error: Invalid value."

Here is my current code:

```
public string gameSettingsUrl;

void Start()
{
    WWW www = new WWW (gameSettingsUrl);
    StartCoroutine(GetConfig(www));
}

IEnumerator GetConfig(WWW www)
{
    yield return www;

    jsonString = www.text;
    Config Config = JsonUtility.FromJson<Config> (jsonString); // I get the error here...
    Debug.Log (Config.GameName);
}
```

jsonString:

```
{
  "GameName": "Smoke Of Death",
  "GameVersion": 1.1,
  "VipsCanSkip": true
}
```

Comment: What's the content of `jsonString`?

Comment: Check that the json isn't surrounded by `"`

Comment: I suppose its possible the JSON isn't valid.  It's impossible for us to tell.  Please add the JSON to the question.

Comment: I added jsonString.

Comment: According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38800533/unity-error-parsing-json-from-remote-source) you shouldn't use the WWW class anymore.